# Difficulty transferring large files using fabric v2 / paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, fabric

I'm updating some code that previously ran on Fabric v1 and worked fine. However now I'm encountering a problem when trying to transfer a file ~200MB in size from local to remote (using, in fabric 2.5.0, `connection.put()`). It appears to transfer, but further attempts to manipulate the file show that only 7 to 10 MB successfully transferred, and my task fails.

I have tried a number of steps to isolate the problem. I can manually transfer the file from one host to another with no issues. I can create a simple script as follows that works, also:

```
    import subprocess

    ret = subprocess.Popen(['scp', '/tmp/filename', 'host:/tmp/']).wait()
    print(ret)
```

but even attempting this exact same code snippet *inside my `fabfile.py`* results in the same behavior as using `connection.put()` -- that is, there is no error message, return code is 0, but the result file on the remote host is 5-10MB and corrupted.

I'm running the task as: `fab -d deploy --target=stage --prompt-for-passphrase` and the debug output (though not all 100% understandable to me) does not immediately seem to have anything relevant to the problem either. Where can I look to debug this and find a working solution?

EDIT: relevant version info:

- Local python: 3.6.8
- Remote python: 3.6.9
- Fabric: 2.5.0
- Paramiko: 2.6.0

Comment: Have you turned on debug logging at the paramiko level?  Also, which version of paramiko?

Comment: i tried enabling paramiko debug logging via the instructions at https://www.fabfile.org/troubleshooting.html but didn't discern any difference in output. Will edit the post now to include relevant version info.

Answer (score 2):

**Just an idea, sometimes it happens with everybody.**

Have you checked your destination server `FREE SPACE` in the destination directory volume? Maybe it is pretty full of logs or etc and you can put there only a few megs?

I can't simulate the case locally but I believe since you can't copy it using scp and Paramiko, that could be a real story :)

Comment: this is always worth checking! but no, the target system has 20G free, and i *can* copy the file outside of fabfile.py, but it fails inside fabfile, even if i use the example subprocess/scp snippet and don't use fabric.Connection.put() .

Comment: so it doesn't work if you call the same `scp` (and args of course) command from fabfile but works from ssh?

Comment: that's correct. i can do it successfully from bash, and i can do it successfully if i put the snippet into a file like `copy.py` and run that, but the same snippet reproduces the error if executed within the fabfile.

Comment: please post your `fabfile.py` contents